# EGL surface limitation size

Tags: display, omxplayer

I wanted to show text over omxplayer on fullHD screen, using separate EGL process.

Test program works without omxplayer, but when omxplayer is playing, program shows 'EGL_NO_SURFACE' error.

After analyse, i find out that omxplayer uses eglCreateWindowSurface functiontoo... and that my problem can be reproduced with just running any 2 EGL applications in parallel on HD display:

```
1) /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_triangles &     ... ok
2) /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_triangles       ... err: EGL_NO_SURFACE
```

running same videoCore example with smaller display can open 2-3 applications. Also with changing source-code by setting nativewindow width&height to 960:540, then 5-6 parallel programs can co-exist, and next-one fails with above error.

So it seems from my test that EGL have some kind of limitation of 150% of fullHd (1920x1080).

Is this true, does someone know that some official limit exists?
... and can it be solved somehow. (no X-server involved)

Answer (score 1):

... the reason was GPU_MEM small size (64mb) inside /boot/config.txt of my rpi.

changing to 128mb resolved the problem.